# Ellipsis in although structure?

Tags: ellipses

I've come across a kinda weird structure and can't figure it out in terms of grammars I know. This is the sentence:

> Although can not totally independent of surrounding temperature, Amphibians do exercise some control over their body temperature through some mechanisms.

As far as I know, in some cases, we can remove subj+to be verb, like "although rich, he looks poor".

Or we can remove the subject in other forms, like "although can cause some problems, I'll continue what I've been doing".

My question is whether or not we can remove "to be" after "can" in such a structure? For example:

> Although can be disappointed by my behaviors

or

> although can disappointed by my behaviors

Anything else regarding the main sentence would be appreciated.

Comment: The sentence is probably misquoted. Please say where you found it and provide a link if possible.

Comment: It's a part of a question in TOEFL preparation tests. However, it is not an official version, and mistakes are not unlikely.

Comment: The _can_ is misplaced and makes the whole thing immediately ungrammatical. Probly copied wrong by a poor student who sold the answers.

Answer (score 1):

A fuller version of the original sentence might read something like

> 1. Although *they [can't be/aren't] totally independent of surrounding temperature*, amphibians do exercise some control over their body temperature through some mechanisms.

Ellipsis should yield this simpler version of the sentence

> 2. Although *not totally independent of surrounding temperature*, amphibians do exercise some control over their body temperature through some mechanisms.

Stated the way it's presently, the sentence, I'm afraid, wouldn't pass muster as a grammatically correct sentence. This is because the subordinate clause *Although can...* has no main verb in it and hence defies the definition of a clause. A truncated version (sentence 2 above) satisfies this condition.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. How about this one? Although can be disappointed by my behaviors,...

Comment: @user463334 Again a faulty construction (and for the same reason as stated above).